# Does cascade happen in 1 transaction?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I save the Product which cascade persist the productMaterial. However, when the productMaterial throws DataIntegrityViolationException the product is rollbacked, which seems like cascade is done in 1 transaction, but i don't find any docs saying that it does. Can someone clarify it for me?

NOTE: I **DO NOT** use `@Transactional`

```
Material material = new Material();
material.setId(1);

Product newProduct = new Product();
ProductMaterial productMaterial = new ProductMaterial();

newProduct.setName("bàn chải");
newProduct.setPrice(1000);
newProduct.setCreatedAt(new Date());
newProduct.setProductMaterials(Collections.singletonList(productMaterial));

productMaterial.setProduct(newProduct);
productMaterial.setMaterial(material);

productRepository.save(newProduct);
```

Here is the hibernate execution:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.vietnam.hanghandmade.entities.Product
        */ insert 
        into
            product
            (created_at, name, price, id) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-11-10 14:55:38.281 TRACE 65729 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Nov 10 14:55:38 JST 2020]
2020-11-10 14:55:38.281 TRACE 65729 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [bàn chải]
2020-11-10 14:55:38.281 TRACE 65729 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [1000]
2020-11-10 14:55:38.281 TRACE 65729 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [OTHER] - [e5729490-a0f8-48e7-9600-eeeba8b8f279]
Hibernate: 
    /* insert com.vietnam.hanghandmade.entities.ProductMaterial
        */ insert 
        into
            product_material
            (material_id, product_id) 
        values
            (?, ?)
2020-11-10 14:55:38.324 TRACE 65729 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2020-11-10 14:55:38.324 TRACE 65729 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [OTHER] - [e5729490-a0f8-48e7-9600-eeeba8b8f279]
2020-11-10 14:55:38.328  WARN 65729 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
2020-11-10 14:55:38.328 ERROR 65729 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: insert or update on table "product_material" violates foreign key constraint "product_material_material_id_fkey"
  Detail: Key (material_id)=(1) is not present in table "material".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** This answer missed the point of the question, which is about “cascading persist” – it talks about “cascading delete” for foreign keys.

The cascading delete or update is part of the action of the system trigger that implements foreign key constraints, and as such it runs in the same transaction as the triggering statement.

I cannot find a place in the fine manual that spells this out, but it is obvious if you think about it: if the cascading delete were run in a separate transaction, it would be possible that the delete succeeds and the cascading delete fails, which would render the database inconsistent and is consequently not an option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you write down the "persist cascade" too otherwise it would be confusing for newbies like me because the question is about cascade persist.

Comment: I am a database guy; I don't know what you mean by "persist". Find out the SQL statements that your code causes, then you will know what happens on the database. But that much is clear: either all deletes happen or none, there is no other possibility.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me. The hibernate just use insert query, but why jpa has cascade type persist?

Comment: Oh. Nvm. Those are some jpa specific stuff. Thank you so much for your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @LaHai Look at the [docementation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-cascade-persist): *The `CascadeType.PERSIST` allows us to persist a child entity along with the parent one.*

Comment: @SternK. I know what it means but the commenter said “ I don't know what you mean by "persist"” so i wonder is it just jpa specification?

Comment: LaHai `persist` means a call of the `EntityManager.persist` method.

Comment: I guess my answer missed the question. I'll delete it, if you un-accept it.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe. No sir, you taught me “ system trigger”. Without you i have no idea that it exists. Thank you. Database only has cascade update and delete, but jpa has cascade persist which just make another insert query, that’s why i was wondering whether it happens in 1 transaction. You might not directly answer my question but i learnt something from you so please don’t delete your answer.