# Does cascade = CascadeType.ALL in JPA require @Transactional when removing?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've a book entity:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private String author;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String isbn;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Page> pages;

    public Book() {
    }

    public Book(String title, String author, String isbn) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    // getters and setters, equals(), toString() .... (omitted for brevity)
}
```

Do I need `@Transactional` on service method

```
delete(){
    repository.deleteById(book.getId());
}
```

to be sure the book + it's pages removed atomically (or rolled back)?
(Please consider `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`)

**Edit:** repository is `CrudRepository` from `Spring Data`

Comment: Try it, but you'll see nothing is permanent without a DB transaction context to commit to the database. Delete by id seems to find the entity and perform JPA's EntityManager.remove on it, which will abide by the cascade remove settings on entity mappings - when the transaction commits or is flushed anyway. This is all atomic based on your database transactions settings.

Comment: So do you mean `deleteById` is wrong?

Comment: I don't follow what mean might be wrong. The jpa deleteById reads and then registers the entity associated with that ID in the JPA repository to be removed. JPA will only issue the delete when in a transaction context, when it is flushed or committed. Turn on logging - if you don't see delete statements, it is because you don't have a transaction. And you should be able to see the book in the database in a db client until the transaction is committed.

Comment: hmm, it seems I forgot to mention: `repository` is `CrudRepository` from `SpringDataJpa`. And it has transactions, right?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr
You do not require @Transactional

**Explaination:**
The cascading delete or update is part of the action of the system trigger that implements foreign key constraints, and as such it runs in the **same transaction** as the triggering statement.

originally answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64764212/11310433